# Load Android's image (in byte array format) in SWT component

Tags: java, android, image, swt, arrays

This is scenario:
Load image in Android OS --> convert it in byte array --> send it to SWT-based application --> load it in a component (I don't know, label, button...).

I receive byte array correctly, but I can't pars it to convert in image.

This is unique code I found in net, that works:

```
byte[] bs = { (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
              (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01,
              (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x22,
              (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02,
              (byte) 0x22, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x10,
              (byte) 0x22, (byte) 0x22, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x01,
              (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x22, (byte) 0x22, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x33,
              (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
              (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x10,
              (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x01,
              (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
              (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x44,
              (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x10,
              (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x01,
              (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x50,
              (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x55,
              (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x10,
              (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x00,
              (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x11, };*/

Color white = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE);
Color black = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK);
Color yellow = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW);
Color red = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);
Color green = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN);
Color blue = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE);
// Create a source ImageData of depth 4
PaletteData palette = new PaletteData(new RGB[] { black.getRGB(), white.getRGB(),
yellow.getRGB(), red.getRGB(), blue.getRGB(), green.getRGB() });



ImageData sourceData = new ImageData(16, 16, 4, palette, 1, b);
```

But doesn't work when I change byte array. How can I set up PaletteData and ImageData in this case??

Comment: This is exception was raised:
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14
I receive it after that peace of code on
    final Image source = new Image(display, sourceData);

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use `ImageIO.read` to parse the image:

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageDataByteArray);
BufferedImage bufImg = ImageIO.read(in);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(bufImg);
myButton.setIcon(icon);
```

As `BufferedImage` is a subclass of `java.awt.Image`, you should be able to use it as is.  I haven't tested this myself, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Note also that you can't randomly change the byte array and expect it to represent a valid image.  If you supply an array that doesn't contain a valid image data (or contains image of an unsupported format), `ImageIO.read` will return `null`.  Have a look at [`ImageIO.read` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29) for more info.

Comment: This peace of code use AWT and swing objects. I need an  org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image

Comment: @user1417608 Have a look at [this code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/ConvertbetweenSWTImageandAWTBufferedImage.htm) for converting `BufferedImage` to `swt.Image`

Comment: No way. I tried swing/AWT objects, but BufferImage is still null after I instantiated it. InputStream seems works...

Comment: @user1417608 The issue may be with the data.  You'll get `null` if the byte array does not contain valid image data.

Comment: I can drawn it using first way I posted. By the way, I can't generalize that method. If I change byte array, `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14` will raised.

Comment: But I'm sure that byte array is working image, and I sure what I load on Android device is an well-formed image (I can load it in Android).
Finally I'm sure what I send from Android arrive equal on in JVM.

Comment: @user1417608 My suggestion: in your JVM, as a debugging method, try saving the byte array into a file, which you can then look at.  Then try opening this file manually with any graphics program - to confirm that it is a valid image.

Comment: Your suggestion told me what I need to hear. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, righ way is this:

```
contact.setImage(pCur.getBlob(0));
publishProgress("befor compress");
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(contact.getImage(), 0, contact.getImage().length);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream); //JPEG or what you want
contact.setImage(stream.toByteArray());
stream.close();
```

Anyway I can't send well-formed byte array. I send byte array with ~1700 byte, and receive an array with ~2800 elements. I don't know why. I'm coding all in UTF-8 string. But print array in file locally works.

Comment: And SWT side, just `final byte[] b = getContent().getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
                            final InputStream tmp_in = new ByteArrayInputStream(b, 0, b.length);
                            Image tmp_i = new Image(display, tmp_in);`

Answer (score 0):

```
****It's work for me****

String filepath = "/sdcard/Image/Image01.jpg";
           File imagefile = new File(filepath);
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try 
            {
                fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100 , baos);    
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 
            System.out.println(baos);
            Bitmap bm1=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b,0, b.length);
            imgViewBitmap.setImageBitmap(bm1);
```